# migrate.exceptions.DatabaseAlreadyControlledError while trying to re create DB in heroku using db_create.py file

Tags: python, database, url, heroku

this is tdb_create.py file under C:\Users\Yasmi\Documents\microblog\flask-psps> which i try to run on heroku using web: gunicorn app:app
init: python db_create.py
upgrade: python db_upgrade.py which is in procfile file under the same folder.
db_create.py doesnt pass , ant figure up why. I did it due to changes in field description in mdels.py file

```sh
C:\Users\Yasmi\Documents\microblog\flask-psps>heroku run init
Running init on flask-psps... up, run.8964 (Free)

  postgres://rydbbszhueldrc:9e71d3c3f199b9dea08833d4a4efcf0e3cc9e1519d77ebc48933fca16f39be9c@ec2-23-21-220-48.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/dfrmo4cc9toudp
basedir is /app

  postgres://rydbbszhueldrc:9e71d3c3f199b9dea08833d4a4efcf0e3cc9e1519d77ebc48933fca16f39be9c@ec2-23-21-220-48.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/dfrmo4cc9toudp
/app/db_repository
SQLALCHEMY_MIGRATE_REPO/app/db_repository
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "db_create.py", line 15, in <module>
    api.version_control(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI, SQLALCHEMY_MIGRATE_REPO)
  File "<decorator-gen-8>", line 2, in version_control
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/migrate/versioning/util/__init__.py", line 167, in with_engine
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/migrate/versioning/api.py", line 250, in version_control
    ControlledSchema.create(engine, repository, version)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/migrate/versioning/schema.py", line 141, in create
    table = cls._create_table_version(engine, repository, version)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/migrate/versioning/schema.py", line 189, in _create_table_version
    raise exceptions.DatabaseAlreadyControlledError
migrate.exceptions.DatabaseAlreadyControlledError
```

```
#!flask/bin/python
from migrate.versioning import api
from config import SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI
from config import SQLALCHEMY_MIGRATE_REPO
from app import db
import os.path
print(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI)
print(SQLALCHEMY_MIGRATE_REPO)
db.create_all()


if  not os.path.exists(SQLALCHEMY_MIGRATE_REPO):
    api.create(SQLALCHEMY_MIGRATE_REPO, 'database repository')
    print ("SQLALCHEMY_MIGRATE_REPO" + SQLALCHEMY_MIGRATE_REPO)
    api.version_control(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI, SQLALCHEMY_MIGRATE_REPO)
else:
    api.version_control(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI, SQLALCHEMY_MIGRATE_REPO, 
api.version(SQLALCHEMY_MIGRATE_REPO))
```

Comment: Im new to stackoverflow and not good at asking the question.

Comment: I get migrate.exceptions.DatabaseAlreadyControlledError

Comment: Welcome to SO.  As far as I can tell you have not asked a question ...

Comment: Couldnt figure out where can i add more code . try to put the  whole err msg , but it complains its too long. can someone also guide me how to add more code to the question?

Answer (score 1):

I have seen this issue. To solve it, just remove the database file **app.db** and rerun the script **db_create.py**

Comment: There is no app.db file; they are using PostgreSQL, not SQLite. You can’t use SQLite on Heroku anyway as there is no persistent filesystem.

Comment: I know you can not. Sometimes you just experimenting using SQLite on your local machine and then you switch to postgreSQL or MySQL but you forget to remove the SQLite files.

Comment: You may have missed the traceback (I fixed the formatting) but you can clearly see in that output that they are connecting to PostgreSQL.